# In detectron 2 how could i get detected object class name and the bounding box x,y coordinates

Tags: object, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, detectron

In detectron 2 how could i get detected object class name and the bounding box x,y coordinates?
[image]

and print it like print(obj_name,x,y)

Answer (score 5):

This code prints the name and coordinates for each detected object.

```
predictor = DefaultPredictor(config)
outputs = predictor(image)
instances = outputs["instances"]
detected_class_indexes = instances.pred_classes
prediction_boxes = instances.pred_boxes

metadata = MetadataCatalog.get(config.DATASETS.TRAIN[0])
class_catalog = metadata.thing_classes

for idx, coordinates in enumerate(prediction_boxes):
    class_index = detected_class_indexes[idx]
    class_name = class_catalog[class_index]
    print(class_name, coordinates)
```

Comment: Hey, the thing_classes has to be explicitly set. Is there a way to access the class names present in dataset itself without having to manually set it first?

Comment: Hi , how to extract the segmented drawing boundary coordinate which instead of the box coordinate ?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract those in the model inference's outputs, for example:

```
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
outputs = predictor(im)
```

- outputs[“instances”]: Instances object with the following fields:

“pred_boxes”: Boxes object storing N boxes, one for each detected instance.

“pred_classes”: Tensor, a vector of N labels in range [0, num_categories).

Ref: https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/models.html